# Any difference between these two in c++?

Tags: c++, syntax

`new char[1]` and `new char`,essentially the same thing,hm?

Answer (score 15):

You have to delete `char[1]` with `delete[]` according to the standard, so not quite identical.

Comment: Yeap, if one ignores this "not quite identical" he plants undefined behavior.

Comment: @sbi: Yes, you do have to `delete[]` what `new char[0]` returns.

Answer (score 2):

The objects created are the same, the (invisible) bookkeeping used is not.

That means that you can *use* the chars in the same way, but you must *delete* them with the matching delete operator (`delete` versus `delete[]`)

Answer (score -1):

No.  char[1] is of type char*, while char is of type char.

Comment: However, `new char` is of type `char *`, so that's not the difference.